# Как перевести отрицательные десятичные числа в двоичные в excel?

Tags: excel, системы-счисления

Необходимо перевести десятичные числа меньшие, чем -512, в двоичные. Функция дес.в.дв не переводит слишком малые числа, а функция основание не работает с отрицательными. Может быть я не знаю о еще какой-то функции, которая будет работать с очень маленькими числами?

Comment: не очень понятно,  какие маленькие числа?

Comment: числа меньшие, чем -512. Например, -6379 и т.п.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вот тут вроде есть решения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693029/bin2dec-for-numbers-longer-than-10-bits-in-excel Только надо помнить, что экселевские формулы придется перевести на русский язык (ну или на каком там у вас эксель)